# How to modify a nested plist when keys are strings

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
("person"
 ("child-1"
  ("grandchild-1a" "grandchild-1a-value"
   "grandchild-1b" "grandchild-1b-value")
  "child-2"
  ("grandchild-2a" "grandchild-2a-value"
   "grandchild-2b" "grandchild-2b-value")))
```

How can `"grandchild-1b-value"` be modified to `"grandchild-1b-value-modified"`? The keys are strings.

Or how can I make a new var that is an equivalent nested plist except for the new value?

Below is how I ended up with the plist. I fed the response from a drakma request to `yason:parse`:

```
(let ((stream (drakma:http-request endpoint
                                   :method :post
                                   :want-stream t
                                   :content-type "application/json"
                                   :content request)))
  (setf (flexi-streams:flexi-stream-external-format stream) :utf-8)
  (let ((response (yason:parse stream :object-as :plist)))
    ***HERE***))
```

Comment: string keys make it difficult to use plist functions, because they all use `eql` to compare the keys. You'll need to use `member ... :test #'string-equal` to find the tail of the plist starting with the key. Then you can replace the second element with the new value.

Comment: Can `yason:parse` return the result in another format that's easier to process?

Comment: @Barmar I discovered st-json has `getjso*` which supports getting a path and `getjso` can be used with `setf`. (So you have to hang onto the modified value's parent for the `setf`.) It also round-trips from json to cl and back accurately with respect to json's empty arrays, nulls, and true/false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER 346 > (pprint
               (subst "grandchild-1b-value-modified"
                      "grandchild-1b-value"
                      '("person"
                        ("child-1"
                         ("grandchild-1a" "grandchild-1a-value"
                          "grandchild-1b" "grandchild-1b-value")
                         "child-2"
                         ("grandchild-2a" "grandchild-2a-value"
                          "grandchild-2b" "grandchild-2b-value")))
                      :test #'equal))

("person"
 ("child-1"
  ("grandchild-1a"
   "grandchild-1a-value"
   "grandchild-1b"
   "grandchild-1b-value-modified")
  "child-2"
  ("grandchild-2a"
   "grandchild-2a-value"
   "grandchild-2b"
   "grandchild-2b-value")))
```